# app crashing using afhttpsessionmanager 3.0

Tags: ios, objective-c

i tried like this  in `webservices.m`

```
  AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
  manager.requestSerializer=[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];

  manager.responseSerializer=[AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

  manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes =[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
[manager POST:meetingupdateurlparams parameters:meetingdictparams progress:nil
      success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable
                responseObject)
 {
     NSLog(@"Complete");
 } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull
             error)
 {
     NSLog(@"Fail %@",error);
 }];
```

i call this service in `Viewcontroller.m`

```
   NSString *updateMeetingurl=@" url ";

NSDictionary *dictparms=@{ params };
[Servicecall meetingupdate:updateMeetingurl meetingupdatedict:dictparms];
[Servicecall setDelegate:self];
```

but i am getting error like this

> -[AFHTTPSessionManager :parameters:progress:success:failure:] unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x792cfcb0'
>   *** First throw call stack:

so any one can help in this issuance...thanks in advance..

Comment: add meetingupdateurlparams and v in question,

Comment: Try to clean your build folder and run again . using : Press Command+Option+Shift+K.

Or from the menu -> Product, press Option on your keyboard and you'll see Clean Build Folder.

Comment: i tried like this..but still existing same error

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

I now see where you're doing wrong.

`POST:meetingupdateurlparams` this part.
Shouldn't you use
`POST:meetingupdateurl` instead?

---

I'm not sure which version of AFNetworking you're using.

But it seems like the method signature you're using does not exist.

Try `POST:parameters:success:failure:` instead of `POST:parameters:progress:success:failure`.

See the [documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.6.1/Classes/AFHTTPSessionManager.html#//api/name/POST:parameters:success:failure:).

Comment: then somehow your method signature is not properly recognized since your error message shows `[AFHTTPSessionManager :parameters:progress:success:failure:]`, not `[AFHTTPSessionManager POST:parameters:progress:success:failure:]`.

Comment: Have you tried `POST:parameters:success:failure:`? There's `POST:parameters:success:failure:` in 3.0 as well, and you're not using the progress anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this USing Afnetworking 3

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"URL"parameters:@{@"paramter":@""} constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        //if you want to pass image file
        if (image) {
            [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8) name:imagename fileName:@"Image.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
        }

    }error:nil];

   AFURLSessionManager *managers = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    managers.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask;
    uploadTask = [managers
                  uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request
                  progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
                      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                      });
                  }
                  completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                      if (error) {

                      } else {
                       // here your response
                      }
                  }];

    [uploadTask resume];
```

Comment: i want send parameters by using post method

Comment: i tried like this also..but getting same exception...                                                 -[AFHTTPSessionManager :parameters:progress:success:failure:] unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x792cfcb0'

Comment: can u please share a link regarding json post request with parameters example source code in objective c..

Comment: but how could i pass parameters ?

Comment: @{@"paramter":@""} this is parameter you can pass as same.

Comment: using AFHTTPSessionManager i am unable to call POST method...getting only GET:method....is there any solution for this?...

Comment: why ? post method existed in  AFHTTPSessionManager class .

Answer (score 0):

I got same error.

It's a issue with Xcode,you should clean build folder(or delete your DerivedData folder,Xcode -> Preferences -> Location -> Locations -> Derived Data).Because Xcode didn't fully clean the older AFNetworking.

Comment: still gettting same error....any one...can help in this issuance...-[AFHTTPSessionManager :parameters:progress:success:failure:] unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x792cfcb0'